# Wordpress: Custom Permalink Parentpage>>category>>post

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

i have created one page and data and also created new template to display post from data category only.

Data(child page) is child of Data Book(parent page) .  tree will be  Databook>> Data.

in Data List of the post are there. so when click on any post will redirect to single.php

for that url would be  http://wordpress.com/post-name

while i need url like    http://wordpress.com/Databook/Data/post-name/

is it possible to get such permalink?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a [permalink structure](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks) for posts that use parts of the post in the URL. Pages aren't in the same structure, so I don't think you can mix them.

But a category structure where Data is a subcategory of Databook should generate URL's with the required structure for your posts if you use the %category% in the permalink setting.

Comment: is it possible to display parent-category in url: for example:   http://mywebsite.com/parent-category/category/post-name

Comment: From the linked documentation for using %category% to generate permalinks: "Nested sub-categories appear as nested directories in the URI.". So I that should work.